# What is the web-template used by many technical documentations on the web?

Tags: web, content-management-system, mkdocs

I found that following websites have the similary style (or theme or template):

- [Keras](https://keras.io/)
- [Conda](https://conda.io/docs/index.html)
- [Thundersvm](https://thundersvm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Chainer](http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/index.html)
  and so on...

It looks lik many tech documentation websites use this style (or template).

My question is:
**What kind of template is that?**

And how I can use it in my tech blog?

Answer (score 0):

They use either [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) or [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) and most of the time the read the docs template for the design.

Comment: The theme can be found at https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, or on GitHub at https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you view source on your first example, keras.io, you can see the tag

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" type="text/css" />
```

Looking at the linked file, you see the comment

```css
/*
 * This file is copied from the upstream ReadTheDocs Sphinx
 * theme. To aid upgradability this file should *not* be edited.
 * modifications we need should be included in theme_extra.css.
 *
 * https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme
 */
```

So I'd recommend checking out https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme, and the page it links to about the theme, https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme.